# Cannot migrate from spring 2.5 to spring 3.0

Tags: spring, maven-2

Problem is a bit stupid but I can't find any spring3.0-with-dependencies.jar. Is it assumed that I should find all necessary dependencies by myself?

May I use dependencies from spring 2.5 in this case? UPD: answer is no, I can't. So, where are the dependencies??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess they don't release them any more. You can have the dependencies automatically if you use maven or ivy. All you need is to define the dependencies in your pom.xml like this:

```
<pom>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</pom>
```

Maven will bring all the dependencies transitively.

Comment: it's very pity. and how can I get dependencies with maven?

Comment: it's automatic. You just add a spring dependency and it downloads all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven, you can get Spring 3.0 jars (and their transitive dependencies) from the [central](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/) repository. Simply add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

For more details, more artifacts, check out [Obtaining Spring 3 Artifacts with Maven](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/) (and please, don't use EBR if you don't need it or I guarantee the nightmare).

Answer (score 0):

Usually the readme.txt file has the dependencies listed for each module. With that you can usually get them easiest from the maven repository... or better yet, with maven (http://maven.apache.org).